After UIAlert dismiss my screen becomes unresponsive IOS
If screen is ideal for 5mins I set AutoLogout it works perfectly but when the UIAlert dialogue shows it logged out but the alert remains showed in the login screen. so below are the code to dismiss my alert dialogue before logout
- (void)dismissAnyAlertControllerIfPresent {
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIViewController *topVC = keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController;

    while (topVC.presentedViewController != nil) {
        topVC = topVC.presentedViewController;
    }

    if ([topVC isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]]) {
        [topVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)didLogout {
    [self dismissAnyAlertControllerIfPresent];
    
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [prefs removeObjectForKey:@"userName"];
        
        [prefs synchronize];

        // Redirect to login page
        [self redirectToLoginPage];
}

- (void)redirectToLoginPage {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        BmobileViewController * login = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"] ;
        login.hideBackbtn = YES;
        login.hideAutoLogoutMsg = YES;
        login.modalPresentationStyle =  UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        [self presentViewController:login animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
        BmobileViewController * login = [storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"] ;
        login.hideBackbtn = YES;
        login.hideAutoLogoutMsg = YES;
        login.modalPresentationStyle =  UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        [self presentViewController:login animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

the code above which one diss miss the alert dialogue runs, then the screen becomes unresponsive
if ([topVC isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]]) {
        [topVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }

`if there is no alert dialogue on ideal state and logged out login screen is working I can click textfields etc.. if I checked with alert on ideal state then logged out screen is not working
I can't able to click textfields in the login screen
for my doubts, I commented the code which goes for login screen and just check the alert dismiss. alert dismissed in the current page and also the current page becomes unresponsive
I am new to IOS development so just give me a advise to handle this error and thanks in advance`

What calls didLogout?

UIAlertController is dismissed automatically when user taps any action button from it. So just do what you want in the action handler, like proceeding logout with the method -didLogout, but don't try to manually dismiss the alert.
